# ThreeJS/Panolens: direction of the camera when panorama entered?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to throw an equirectangular image into [Panolens](https://pchen66.github.io/Panolens/) and simply 1st get the same panorama viewer as can be visible below:

- https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html
- https://www.chiefarchitect.com/products/360-panorama-viewer/

Since Panolens.js is a wrapper of Three.js I expected the same result as when I throw my image into the 1st link above. (drag & drop it) - camera looks into the center of the image.

What I get instead is : camera looks into the left most area of the panorama image.

I solve this using

```
panorama.addEventListener( 'enter-fade-start', function() {
        viewer.getControl().target.set(10, -2, 0);
        viewer.getControl().update();
        //viewer.tweenControlCenter( new THREE.Vector3(2, -1, 1), 2000 );
});
```

But when I move to another panorama and come back, this code does not seem to have any effect (althought event is properly triggered).

How can I make the camera look into the same direction each time I come back to my panorama? (I'm switching between multiple panoramas).

Basically I don't seem to understand vectors properly and where 0,0,0 is each time I come back to panorama, since It seems to be working differently based on where the camera is facing.

Any tips/links/explanations very much welcome.

Comment: Any chance you could show a working demo? I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean "when i move to another panorama and come back", would be easier to help if you set up an example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Marquizzo thanks I seem to have overcomplicated things; it works simply using the answer I just posted (.tweenControlCenter() method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I over complicated things it seems. The solution is **to only use**:

```
viewer.tweenControlCenter( new THREE.Vector3(10, -2, 0), 0 );
```

inside "enter-fade-start". And that's it.

Much of docs is a bit misleading with saying you have to call `.update()` on control and setting .target properly etc, but that does not seem to work as I expected.

Relevant example also here: https://codepen.io/pchen66/pen/LLgxME